# lastInsertId - PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Hello guys after inserting a record I want to record the last ID of the register, I'm using PDO lastInsertId () and write in a $ _SESSION, but I'm not getting what is missing in my code I have an error message

```
<?php 
session_start();

define("SERVER", "localhost");
define("BASES", "databases");
define("USER", "userbases");
define("PASS", "******");

class Sql extends PDO {
    private $conn;
    public function __construct(){
            try {
                $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".BASES.";host=".SERVER, USER, PASS);
        }catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Database Error: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
        catch(Exception $e){
                echo "Generic error: ".$e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function query($rawQuery, $params = array()){
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($rawQuery);
        $this->setParams($stmt, $params);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
    }

    public function query($rawQuery, $params = array()){
       $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($rawQuery);
       $this->setParams($stmt, $params);
       $stmt->execute();
       return $this->conn->lastInsertId(); //agreement by @dennisgon
   }

}

/* INSERT */

$query = "INSERT INTO User(Name,Email) VALUES ('Cledson Stefanato','teste@gmal.com');";
$txt = new Sql();
$txt->query($query);

$_SESSION["RECORD"] = $txt->lastInsertId();

echo "Recorded: ".$_SESSION["RECORD"];

?>
```

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function lastInsertId() on null in /home/xxxx/index.php:24 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/xxxx/index.php on line 24

Comment: You're extending PDO but then you're instantiating a separate private PDO object in your constructor, which doesn't make sense -- you shouldn't do both. And then you're overriding public methods with private methods, which makes them uncallable -- so I'm not sure how you're even getting the error you've posted, which doesn't even match line numbers with the code you've posted.

Comment: Detected missing return parameters $ this->conn->lastInsertId(); I didn't realize I was in "private" I edited here for "public". It worked, thanks for your message :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

last lastInsertId() is a function on PDO class, the problem is in your class you return prepare function in think the best way is you must return the lastInsertId() in your function query like this

//---------------Conseld
I supplemented by using two different classes and functions as I had suggested.

```
<?php
/*CONNECTION WITH DATABASES*/
define("SERVER", "localhost");
define("BASES", "databases");
define("USER", "userbases");
define("PASS", "******");

/*DATABASE AND FUNCTION CONNECTION CLASS*/
class QueryPDO extends PDO{

    private $conn;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".BASES.";host=".SERVER, USER, PASS);
    }
    /*INSERT, UPDATE AND DELETE FUNCTION*/
    public function query($rawQuery, $params = array()){
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($rawQuery);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $this->conn->lastInsertId();
    }

}

/*DATABASE AND FUNCTION CONNECTION CLASS*/
class SelectPDO extends PDO{

    private $conn;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".BASES.";host=".SERVER, USER, PASS);
    }
    /*LISTAR DADOS*/
    public function query($rawQuery, $params = array()){
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($rawQuery);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
    }

    public function select($rawQuery, $params = array()):array{
        $stmt = $this->query($rawQuery, $params);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

}

/*INSERT - MAY ALSO USE WITH UPDATE AND DELETE*/
$query = "INSERT INTO User(
                Nome,
                Email
                ) VALUES (
                'Cledson A Stefanato',
                'txt@gmail.com'
                );";
$txt = new QueryPDO();

/*SESSION RECORD, LAST REGISTRATION*/
$_SESSION["RECORD"] = $txt->query($query);
echo "Recorded: ".$_SESSION["RECORD"];


/*LIST*/
$query = "SELECT * FROM Cadastro";
$txt = new SelectPDO();
$result = $txt->select($query);

//echo json_encode($result);
//echo var_dump($result);

foreach ($result as $dados){
?>
<div style="color: red; font-size: 15px">
    <?php
    echo $dados["Nome"]. "<br />";
    echo $dados["Email"]. "<br />";
    ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hello friend now another problem appeared.
I am listing the records now the error below appears.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on string in /home/xxx/xxxx/index.php:35 Stack trace: #0 /home/xxx/xxx/index.php(42): Sql->select('SELECT * FROM C...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/xxxx/xxxx/index.php on line 35


List data script below

$query = "SELECT * FROM User";
$txt = new Sql();
$result = $txt->select($query);
echo json_encode($result);

Comment: hai you must separate the function between select and insert, update delete because it has different behavior

Comment: How to do this? I did not understand. Because I put everything inside a class and just called the functions

Comment: Edit what you corrected, see insert and list as I did. Would you help me?

Comment: yeah you can use like that, but you can't use the same function name in the class

Comment: I separated the classes one for select and one for insert, update and delete. I have always used MySQLi I am migrating to PDO, I will use listing I will use foreach and I will need a pagination, you tell me a Google style? Thanks for all this help :-)